# Is it possible to the change filenames of feature.xml and elements.xml on a sharepoint server?

Tags: sharepoint, moss

Is it possible to the change filenames of feature.xml and elements.xml on a sharepoint server? If so, how?

Thanks

Regards
Prasanth

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot change the name of the feature.xml file. However you can change the the name of elements.xml. If you change the name of the elements.xml you have to change the reference to this file in the corresponding feature.xml.